# Experian QAS Soap Request c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I need to make an request to an Experian service using SOAP.

The documentation is shocking, and the example code given is even worse. SO I was hoping that someone out there might be able to help.

To begin with, I'd like to just get a response from the test call, using 
https://ws.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx?op=DoGetExampleAddresses After that, I'm pretty sure that I could work it out.

Can anyone help?

```
        ///Service Reference
        Experian.QAS.QAAuthentication authentication = new Experian.QAS.QAAuthentication();
        authentication.Username = "username";
        authentication.Password = "password";

        Experian.QAS.QAQueryHeader header = new Experian.QAS.QAQueryHeader();
        header.QAAuthentication = authentication;

        Experian.QAS.QAGetExampleAddresses body = new Experian.QAS.QAGetExampleAddresses();
        body.Country = "GBR";
        body.Layout = "QADefault";

        //I think this is the wrong call to post the request
        Experian.QAS.DoGetExampleAddressesRequest request = new Experian.QAS.DoGetExampleAddressesRequest(header, body);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment on the final line of your code is correct, that's the SOAP request object for the operation, rather than the operation itself.

Do you have a class that inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` in the sample code somewhere (e.g. called `QASOnDemandIntermediary`)?

You need to instantiate an instance of that class, assign your authentication object to it, and then call the method on the client that performs the operation you need to do, so for example:

```
// Create authentication object
QAAuthentication authentication = new QAAuthentication();
authentication.Username = "MyUserName";
authentication.Password = "MyPassword";

// Create SOAP header and assign authentication parameters to it
QAQueryHeader header = new QAQueryHeader();
header.QAAuthentication = authentication;

// Create service client
QASOnDemandIntermediary client = new QASOnDemandIntermediary();
client.QAQueryHeaderValue = header;

// Create service request
QAGetExampleAddresses request = new QAGetExampleAddresses();
request.Country = "GBR";
request.Layout = "QADefault";

// Call the web service
QAExampleAddress[] result = client.DoGetExampleAddresses(request);

// Use the result
foreach (var example in result)
{
    // Use the examples
}
```

I don't have ready access to the exact sample code you're using, so some of the type names I've used may not be 100% correct, but they should be similar.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thank you so much, that got me on way. You are better than the Experian documentation.